# Object is possibly 'undefined' bug in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

if I have:

```
enum Value {
  A = "A",
  B = "B",
  C = "C",
}

const options = [
  {value: "A", label: "A"},
  {value: "B", label: "B"},
  {value: "C", label: "C"}
]

const getValue = (value: Value) => ({
   x: options.find((opt) => opt.value === value).value
})
```

Typescript complains saying: `Object is possibly 'undefined'` but how can that be possible?

The values are locked, the options are locked. it can never not be undefined. the only exception is if you pass something into `getValue(5)` like that. but then Typescript would catch that at the higher level, no?

Comment: Basically, TypeScript isn't smart enough. Also, the typings for `find` are like that.

Comment: Options is not "locked". The array is still mutable: there's no compile-time guarantee that it won't be modified at runtime so the compiler conservatively rejects. Same reason the return type of `Object.keys` is `string[]` instead of `(keyof typeof foo)[]`. Any time you use runtime reflection you'll run into that issue.